# JSON time offset (Trello)

Tags: json, trello

I'd like to create Trello cards over the Trello API. I'am able to create a card with:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.trello.com/1/lists/{LIST_ID}/cards?name=TEST9&due=2014-05-08T08:00:00&key={APP_KEY}&token={TOKEN}'
```

However, I can't determine my time offset for the due date:

```
2014-05-08T08:00:00.{OFFSET}
```

My Timezone is CET (Europe/Berlin), how can I tell Trello this with the time offset?

Comment: you should ask them, as this is specific to Trello API. Another option would be to send the actual time in their Timezone by initially calculating the difference between your clock and theirs; thus, there would not be a need for sending your offset.

Answer (score 5):

I could not find it in the documentation, but I am quite sure Trello stores the due dates in *UTC*. So as the comment already suggests, convert your timestamp to their timezone (which would be *UTC*).

Comment: Adrian is correct, Trello stores all due dates in `UTC`